# AKS nodepool in a failed state, PODS all pending

Tags: azure, azure-aks

yesterday I was using kubectl in my command line and was getting this message after trying any command. Everything was working fine the previous day and I had not touched anything in my AKS.

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2022-01-11T12:57:51-05:00 is after 2022-01-11T13:09:11Z

After doing some google to solve this issue I found a guide about rotating certificates:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/certificate-rotation

After following the rotate guide it fixed my certificate issue however all my pods were still in a pending state so I then followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/update-credentials

Then one of my nodepools started working again which is of type user but the one of type system is still in a failed state with all pods pending.

I am not sure of the next steps I should be taking to solve this issue. Does anyone have any recommendations? I was going to delete the nodepool and make a new one but I can't do that either because it is the last system node pool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ***`API version older than 2020-03-01`*** for creating AKS cluster.

There are few limitations apply when you create and manage AKS clusters that support system node pools.

> • An API version of 2020-03-01 or greater must be used to set a node
> pool mode. Clusters created on API versions older than 2020-03-01
> contain only user node pools, but can be migrated to contain system
> node pools by following ***[update pool mode steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-system-pools#update-existing-cluster-system-and-user-node-pools)***.
>
> • The mode of a node pool is a required property and must be
> explicitly set when using ARM templates or direct API calls.

**You can use the Bicep/JSON code provided in [***`MS Document`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/2021-10-01/managedclusters?tabs=bicep) to create the AKS cluster as there is using upgaded API version.**

You can also follow this ***[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-system-pools#create-a-new-aks-cluster-with-a-system-node-pool)*** if you want to Create a new AKS cluster with a system node pool and add a dedicated system node pool to the existing AKS cluster.

The following command adds a dedicated node pool of ***`mode type system`*** with a default count of three nodes.

```
az aks nodepool add \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --cluster-name myAKSCluster \
    --name systempool \
    --node-count 3 \
    --node-taints CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoSchedule \
    --mode System
```